# Remove only the text between tags in jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

This is a chunk of my HTML code.

```
<label> This text needs to be removed
<input id="given-name" name="given-name" type="text">
</label>
```

Using jsoup I want to remove the above mentioned text so that I get the following result -

```
 <label>
 <input id="given-name" name="given-name" type="text">
 </label>
```

How do I achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document doc = ...;
Element label = doc...; // Get the <label> element

if (label != null) {
    for (TextNode node : label.textNodes())
        node.remove(); // remove element text

    System.out.println(doc.html());
}
```